# How to listen/write to a FutureProvider using providerContainer?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a `FutureProvider`, but I need to listen to it from outside the `context`, so I'm using the `ProviderContainer` for it.

```
final providerContainer = ProviderContainer();

final futureProvider = FutureProvider<String?>((ref) async {
  return await foo();
});
```

How do I get its value, and update it, using `providerContainer`?

Comment: You should have only one ProviderContainer in your entire program... generally the one that the top-level ProviderScope creates.  Not sure why you'd create a new one.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I did realize that the container is not the same instance as the rest so it does not update the views if I use it. You say there's already a container created by ProviderScope, how can I access that one in order to access the providers outside of a widget?

Comment: You should not be accessing providers outside the view, or actions triggered directly or indirectly by the view.  If you do that, you'll have a chain of "ref" to be able to use with provider access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is given in the comments: it is not possible to access using the `providerContainer` since it is not the same instance. Instead, pass the `WidgetRef` to wherever you need to access the provider.

Comment: I expanded my answer by adding information about `ProviderScope.containerOf(context)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
  final providerContainer = ProviderContainer();

  final futureProvider = FutureProvider<String?>((ref) async {
    return await foo();
  });

  final AsyncValue<String?> result = providerContainer.read(futureProvider);

  final String? data = result.value;
```

or use any other method/getter from `AsyncValue`.

---

Still, if you really need to access the parent container, you can do it like this:

```dart
final container = ProviderScope.containerOf(context);
container.read(provider);
```

This can also be useful in a dialogue situation, when a provider override was previously used:

```dart
Builder(
  builder: (context) => ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (c) => ProviderScope(
          parent: ProviderScope.containerOf(context),
          child: const AlertDialog(/*...*/),
          ),
        );
      },
    child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Except that this ProviderContainer has nothing to do with the singleton instance being used by the rest of the app, and that's my first comment to the original question.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Yes, I agree with you. I thought the author meant just "how to do it", although of course we have to use `UncontrolledProviderScope` to pass this container around